# How do you latinize the name "Cole"?

Tags: declension, names, latinization

Salvete,

I can't figure out how I would go about latinizing my name. I would also
appreciate a declension of my latinized name. I was thinking that maybe "Colus," 
"Colis," or "Coleus" could work, though the vocative of "Coleus" would be "Colee," which seems awkward with the double "e."

Gratias vobis in antecesso ago.

Comment: I'll write a proper answer later, but for now I would strongly advise against _Cōleus_, which refers to a part of the male genitalia!

Answer (score 4):

Cole can be either seen as a pet form of Nicholas, or apparently as an independent name derived from the Old English nickname Cola. See [here](https://namemeaningsonline.com/meaning-of-the-name-cole/), [here](https://www.surnamedb.com/Surname/Cole), [here](https://www.behindthename.com/name/cole), [here](https://www.ancestry.com/name-origin?surname=cole).

Since the Latin for Nicholas is Nicolaus (or Nicholaus), the former interpretation gives **Colaus**. In Italian there is the historical precedent of Nicola Gabrini, a 14th century politician, being known as Cola di Rienzo. *Colaus* would be declined as *Nicolaus* and with the same vowel quantities: *(Nī)Cŏlāus*.

The latter interpretation gives a straight **Cola**, which doesn't sound *too* unnatural in Latin because it exists as [a suffix](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-cola), e.g. in *agricola* (agricultor), but obviously has the problem of sounding like a drink. *Cola* would be declined as *agricola*.

Answer (score 2):

> I agree with @Vincenzo that *Cola* would probably work well, not only because in Latin there exists the word *agricola*, meaning "farmer", but especially since *Agricola* was a real name.

Gnaeus Iulius Agricola was a politician and general who lived during the Early Roman Empire. He conquered Britain and governed on that region over quite a long period. Recalled in Rome, he died after some years in obscure circumstances; Tacitus insinuates Domitian gave the order to poison him.

> In analogy with the name *Agricola* - and if you like it, of course -  *Cola* could be treated as a masculine noun of the first declension.